# How can I set colors on my WSL Ubuntu app?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the `ls` command returning ridiculously illegible blue text, as below:

[image]

How anyone (not colour blind) could ever justify using such a colour on a black background is beyond me.

Comment: Yes its not clearly visible. You can change the color scheme in command prompt properties. Or change it with `PS1` variable in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` in other rc files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this applies to WSL but I'd assume so:

Few years ago Microsoft [replaced the legacy color palette](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/08/02/updating-the-windows-console-colors/) for console windows, using significantly more readable soft colors. However, these new defaults weren't applied to existing installations.

As a simple way to change colors, Microsoft released [a color tool as part of the new Terminal app](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/master/src/tools/ColorTool/README.md).

[More details can be found in this blog post.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-the-windows-console-colortool/)

Comment: The GitHub page for `Colortool` is a 404 error page.  Blog just links back to the Windows Terminal Github project (which does not have the tool).  Did you verify this information before you submitted this answer?

Comment: The tool is no longer available, only applied to the default command prompt (not Powershell), the entire effort was turned in Windows Terminal which a different project then that blog post describes.  *Even if you could provide a working link to the tool it wouldn't apply to WSL*

Comment: @Ramhound I copied the URL from the announcement, but didn't expect the sources to get moved, which I've fixed now. The Color Tool is now part of the new Terminal app's repository, which broke the old links. It's still there and should still apply. Can't treat it though, since all my colors got updated as expected.

Comment: You say, "However, these new defaults weren't applied to existing installations.", yet my WSL Ubuntu installation is a few days old, I don't think it falls under existing installations. But thanks for the tool link, I'll check it out.

Comment: @ProfK Weißt I mean is, these defaults are set for fresh Windows installations, but they weren't changed for Windows upgrades. The tool should always be able to change them.